# how to get dates between two given dates in sql

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

[image: i have this table]

in the above table i need sql query by which i can return dates between Leave_from and Leave_to from leave_log Table (eg, Leave_from 30/07/2018 Leave_to 02-08-2018) i need dates like

```
30/07/2018 
01/08/2018
02/08/2018
```

by which i will try next query

2) is der any query or function which will check before insert into leave_log table whether the leaves applied by the employees for particular date (01-08-2018) does not cross quota of 10% per Team

Thanks  in advance

Comment: Are you aware of `between` and `triggers`?

Comment: I m beginner dont know much about between and trigger

Comment: Learning is fun. Use google.

Comment: Thanks but that's not an good idea

Comment: Can Someone Help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should have a `calender` table if yes, then you need to `JOIN` with your actual table to `calender` table. In other way you can use recursive `CTE` option :

```
with t as (
     select id, leave_frm, leave_to
     from table
     union all
     select id, dateadd(day, 1, leave_frm), leave_to
     from t
     where leave_frm < leave_to
)

select *
from t
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Comment: Can u guide with calendar table please

Comment: @RajJadhav. . . Take a look - http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calendar/145206/

Comment: @RajJadhav. . . A calendar table is a permanent table containing a list of dates and various components of those dates. also refer . . . https://www.sqlshack.com/designing-a-calendar-table/

Comment: thanks a lot it helped me for the first query can u tell me how i can prepare second condition in php

Comment: Can Someone Help me please